# How to encrypt the data entered by the user?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

As part of my job, assume I have a table

```
create table bank(accountnumber int, accountholdername varchar(50),
                  amount decimal(10,2),lastdrawn varchar(5))
```

Now my requirement is all table data is confidential so at the time of insertion only the data
has to be entered in table in encrypted format.

And if we want to see the encrypted data then we have to decrypt it.

But finally always the data in a table should be in encrypted format.

Now can I resolve this problem? Can anyone help with step by step explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use several encryption algorithms to encrypt data before inserting to database:

1. MD5 encryption http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/rick/archive/2005/05/18/4118.aspx
2. BASE 64 Encryption  http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/529500-base64-decoding
3. SHA or DES Encryption. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10154/NET-Encryption-Simplified

Comment: hi, i have to encrypt the data in sqlserver only , not from asp or c# or java